# migration from angular 5 to angular 7

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, migration, eventsource

Yesterday i have migrated my application from Angular 5 to angular 7. In that process i have changed EventSource to EventSourcePolyfill as suggested while running the application. But since then i am facing a strange issue. This is what i am getting the issue in console as follows:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'heartbeatTimeout' of undefined
    at new EventSourcePolyfill (eventsource.js:155)
    at AppFooterComponent.push../src/app/layout/footer/footer.component.ts.AppFooterComponent.connect (footer.component.ts:133)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (footer.component.ts:52)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:196)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:134)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:77)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at AsyncAction.dispatch (timer.js:31)
    at AsyncAction.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/scheduler/AsyncAction.js.AsyncAction._execute (AsyncAction.js:63)
    at AsyncAction.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/scheduler/AsyncAction.js.AsyncAction.execute (AsyncAction.js:51)
```

This is what i did in my code:

```
import { EventSourcePolyfill } from 'ng-event-source';

let source = new EventSourcePolyfill('/api/v1/events/register');
```

Can any one suggest me how to get rid of this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: The origin of the error is in footer.component.ts(line 133), kindly check it there. heartbeatTimeout might not be in the properties of the object you are trying to read.

Comment: When i comment it out then it works properly. I mean the EventSourcePolyfill is commented the it works fine. Its not the issue with the footer.component.ts. The code in footer.component.ts of EventSourcePoyfill breaks. Please suggest.

Comment: Have you used `ng update` command for migration? It has ability to refactor some breaking changes? Have you followed instructions on [update.angular.io](https://update.angular.io/)? There are some steps with RxJS migration.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass additional parameters, as

```
eventSource = new EventSourcePolyfill(url,
    { heartbeatTimeout: 5000, connectionTimeout: 5000, headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic foo' }});
```